# How to delete a redis stream after success processing

Tags: redis, symfony4, symfony-messenger

I use redis as transport in messenger, I thought that after processing a flow the deletion was automatic but alas not. I do not know how to delete a repeat stream when the processing has been carried out with success.

I use symfony 4.4.latest and redis server 6.0

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean delete the all stream or only the processed messages?

Comment: @GuyKorland I wish when I process a message that it can be deleted from the queue

Comment: Why not use pub/sub if you don’t need retention?

Answer (score 4):

The way to do it is by using [XTRIM](https://redis.io/commands/xtrim) command.

You can call you process couple of messages you trim the stream to retain only the messages that were not processed. By, calling [XLEN](https://redis.io/commands/xlen) you can get the stream size and if you subtract the amount of messages you processed you should be left with the right argument for the XTRIM.

Comment: Thank you

I find it hard to understand how to do it. Is there a way when the symfony handler retrieves the message to process, how to retrieve the message id so that at the end of processing by the handler
  symfony, I can remove this message from the redis stream.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Simple steps:

1. Read a stream message and keep its ID.
2. When you are done processing the message use the [XDEL](https://redis.io/commands/xdel)  command to delete specific entries from the redis stream.

BTW redis streams are not supposed to be used like this, better use pub/sub functionality as @Dudo mentioned. This is a good introduction to redis streams: https://redis.io/topics/streams-intro

Comment: problem with pub/sub is that it does not guarantee at-least-once delivery

Answer (score -1):

Want to add here that in Symfony 5 `?delete_after_ack=true` was added.

```
MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN=redis://localhost:6379/messages?delete_after_ack=true
```

Why the default in Symfony 5 is false. The default in Symfony 6 is `true` so Symfony 6 will automatically remove acked message.

See also: https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html#redis-transport

There are also other parameters like `delete_after_reject` or `stream_max_entries` which trims the stream. Keep in mind `stream_max_entries` is trim messages aways which also are not processed. So it should be a high enough value.